# How do I stop iOS from converting a small pointing right triangle character into a rectangluar boxed triangle symbol?

Tags: ios, unicode

[image]
I've tried entering the small pointing right triangle and the right arrow characters, both are converted by iOS into rectangular icons with a right triangle and a right arrow, respectively. Can I declare a different font to stop this from happening? Or is there a default setting I need to turn off?

All a want is a black small pointing right triangle:

Decimal Hex
▸   9656    ▸   25B8

Here is the Code:

```
NSString *title = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d payments of %@ ➡ ▶", duration, [Utils formatPrice:payment]];
   [button setTitle: title forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you entering those characters? Through code? Are you using character codes or are you pasting the character directly?

Comment: I tried it both ways, had the same result.

Comment: So iOS is automatically creating that blue box around those characters? You aren't using a custom control that would do that?

Comment: Yes. Just those characters, none of the other text.

Comment: it's exactly the same behavior for web pages, in the default browser and regular HTML code with those HTML entities it converts *arrow* to *button with the arrow*, and there's no way to override this behavior, except replacing this html entity with another one.

Answer (score 29):

This is not about changing font, but about unicode variation.
On Unicode 6.1, one unicode code point can have multiple glyphs, and you can choose those using Variation Selectors.

For about emoji, you can use U+FE0E(@"\U0000FE0E") to choose text style graph.
(And, U+FE0F(@"\U0000FE0F") is for Apple Color Emoji).

For example, LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE's unicode code point is U+25C0(@"\U000025C0"), and you can specify not to use Apple Color Emoji but non-color symbol like @"\U000025C0\U0000FE0E".

Also, there is some difference between iOS emulator(for iOS6 on Mountain Lion) and actual device(iOS6) about Variation Selector handling, probably because Mountain Lion have more support for Unicode 6.1, I guess.

For example, if I don't specify the selectors, I see non-color triangle on iOS6 device, but Apple Color triangle on iOS6 simulator(on Mountain Lion), for UIBarButton.

So, it is nice to check both simulator and actual device, but it looks more safe to use Unicode Variation Selectors always anyway.

Comment: Adding the variation selector seems to work on iOS 6 but not on iOS 5.

Comment: Had this issue in iOS 9 with CSS `content: "\25C0";` - changing it to `content: "\25C0 \FE0E"` seemed to fix it for me (pending some QA).

Comment: Worked for me creating html for epubs. Changing `\u21a9` to `\u21a9\uFE0E` seemed to force iOS to not use the emoji glyphs

Comment: "\u{25B6}\u{FE0E}" worked for me in swift 3.2 Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

It was kind of challenging to force the Browser to render the HTML Entity on iPads/iPhones, but I managed to find the solution, and here's the trick.

Instead of using HTML entities directly:

```
&#9664; <!-- ◀ BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE -->
&#9654; <!-- ▶ BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE -->
```

I created supportive elements in HTML, with the classes:

```
<span class="left-pointing-triangle">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="right-pointing-triangle">&nbsp;</span>
```

With the use of CSS [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element made the override of the content:

```
.left-pointing-triangle::after {
  content: "\25C0 \FE0E";
}
.right-pointing-triangle::after {
  content: "\25B6 \FE0E";
}
```

The important part is to use `content: "\25C0 \FE0E"`, instead of just symbol itself `content: "\25C0"`. It works flawlessly on both iPads and iPhones of different iOS versions.

Answer (score 12):

I use these unicode characters to stop iOS from fiddling:

Right-triangle: ► (&#x25ba)

Left-triangle: ◄ (&#x25c4)

### Update

If further triangles are what you seek:

Up-triangle: ▲ (&#x25b2)

Down-triangle: ▼ (&#x25bc)

Comment: Any idea how to get bottom and top triangle?

Comment: Worked in Android Chrome Mobile.

Comment: Works like magic. This should probably be the accepted answer (for my needs, at least).

Answer (score 0):

To show the black right arrow emoji, we should choose `&#9656;` instead of `&#9654;` or `&#9658;` in order to avoid Apple Emoji

`&#9656;` is smaller than the other two, but you can set the `font-size` to adjust it.
Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can render small triangles in SVG on modern browsers.

Right Triangle:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="16" viewBox="0 0 5 10">
  <polygon fill="black" points="0,0 5,5 0,10" />
</svg>
```

Left Triangle:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="16" viewBox="0 0 5 10">
  <polygon fill="black" points="0,5 5,0 5,10" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

That appears to be the system font glyph for 25B8. I would assume the same would happen for 2B05 (Leftwards Black Arrow) and 25C0 (Black Left-Pointing Triangle). They are apart of Apple Emoji.

You may want to try using a different font.

Hope that helps.

Comment: different font haven't helped, as I'm using non-default font-face. It just replaces html entities with the buttons

Comment: It's not an issue of fonts, it's an issue of HTML entities being converted by iOS software.

Comment: @AlexBanman The original question is about a text string in a UIButton control. HTML was not being used; therefore is was not an issues of HTML entities. The actual issue was multiple glyphs for unicode code points see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950876/1298400.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Is the proper name for those symbols Unicode glyphs? I may off the mark again, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There are a couple of things going on here. First is the Unicode code point. This is an entry in the Unicode table that defines a code point and description. For example, code point 25B6: BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE is defined [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf). Second are glyphs. Glyphs are pictures that are shown to a user. There can be multiple glyphs for each code point. The variation selector tells the UI which glyph variation should be used for a specific code point.